# Memory corruption when closing Unix Socket

Tags: c++, class, sockets, valgrind, eigen

I've designed a class that handles several UNIX socket operations such as sending and receiving single values or arrays. The point was just to unify server and client methods in order to use the same code in both cases.

My `unix_socket.hpp`:

```
#ifndef __SOCKET_HPP
#define __SOCKET_HPP

#ifndef EIGEN_NO_DEBUG
#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG
#endif

#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

#define DEFAULT_SOCKET_PATH (std::string(getenv("HOME"))+std::string("/msock")).data()
#define SERVER_MODE 0
#define CLIENT_MODE 1

using Eigen::VectorXd;
using std::string;

struct message{
    char type;    
    double value; 
};

class unix_socket{
public:
    double v_sent,v_recvd;
    char c_sent, c_recvd;

    VectorXd vector_recvd;
    VectorXd vector_sent;

    int sock, client_sock;
    unsigned int t,len;

    int mode; //0 server, 1 client

    struct sockaddr_un local,remote;

    string path;

    unix_socket();
    unix_socket(int sc_mode);
    ~unix_socket();

    void initSocket(const char* sock_path);
    void initSocket(const char* sock_path, const int sc_mode);
    void wait();
    void closeSocket();

    int sendMsg(const char type, const double value);
    int receiveMsg();
    int sendVectorXd(const VectorXd& values);
    int receiveVectorXd();

};
#endif
```

and `unix_socket.cpp`:

```
#include "unix_socket.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using Eigen::VectorXd;

unix_socket::unix_socket(){
    v_sent=0;
    v_recvd=0;
    mode=0;
}

unix_socket::unix_socket(int sc_mode){
    v_sent=0;
    v_recvd=0;
    mode=sc_mode;
}

unix_socket::~unix_socket(){
    close(sock);
    close(client_sock);
    //system((std::string("rm ")+path).data());
}

void unix_socket::initSocket(const char* sock_path, const int sc_mode){

    if (sc_mode==0){
            // socket server 
        if (mode != sc_mode) mode=sc_mode;

        if ((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(local.sun_path, sock_path);
        unlink(local.sun_path);
        len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
        if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
            close(sock);
            perror("bind"); exit(1);
        }

    } else if(sc_mode==1) {
            // socket client
        if (mode != sc_mode) mode=sc_mode;
        if ((client_sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(remote.sun_path, sock_path);
        len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
        if (connect(client_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connected.\n");
        // ---
    } else printf("Invalid sc_mode argument: %d\n",sc_mode);
    path=string(sock_path);
}

void unix_socket::initSocket(const char* sock_path){
    initSocket(sock_path,mode);
}

void unix_socket::wait(){
    if (mode==0){
        if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(1);
        }
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((client_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connected!\n");
    } else printf("Invalid call to wait(): mode %d\n, must be 0",mode);
}

void unix_socket::closeSocket(){
    //close(sock);
    close(client_sock); 
}

int unix_socket::sendMsg(const char type, const double value){
    struct message msg;
    msg.type=type;
    msg.value=value;
    int n = send(client_sock, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("send");
        return -1;
    } 
    c_sent=msg.type;
    v_sent=msg.value;
    return 0;
}

int unix_socket::receiveMsg(){
    struct message msg;
    int n = recv(client_sock, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("recv");
        return -1;
    } 
    c_recvd=msg.type;
    v_recvd=msg.value;
    return 0;
}

int unix_socket::sendVectorXd(const VectorXd& values){
    sendMsg('A',values.rows());
    for (int i = 0; i < values.rows(); ++i){
        if (i<(values.rows()-1)) sendMsg('V',values(i));
        else sendMsg('L',values(i));
    }
    return 0;
}

int unix_socket::receiveVectorXd(){
    receiveMsg();
    if (c_recvd=='A' && v_recvd>1){
        vector_recvd=VectorXd::Zero(v_recvd);
        for (int i = 0; i < vector_recvd.rows(); ++i){
            receiveMsg();
            vector_recvd(i)=v_recvd;
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Overall everything seems to be working fine, when testing with simple `.cpp`'s that send large (~1000) VectorXd in both directions. However, when using in a more complex program, as posted below, I'm getting a `malloc(): memory corruption:` error, everytime I close the socket by calling `unix_socket::closeSocket()` **on the server side** (context: the program is sending and receiving data to and from a Webots instance running a robot controller which acts as socket client):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "../socket/unix_socket.hpp"
#include "asm.hpp"

#include <sstream>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace Eigen;    
using namespace std;

int start_webots(const char* world){
    //starting webots as a child process with known PID
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        printf("Starting webots...");
        execlp("/usr/local/bin/webots","webots",world,NULL);
        printf("WEBOTS AUTOCLOSED!");
        exit(1);
    }
    else printf("Webots PID: %i\n", pid);
    return pid;
}    

VectorXd asmParams(bool fall_break, int periods, double delay){
    VectorXd p(5); 
    if (fall_break==true) p << 1,-1,1,periods,delay;
    else p << 1,-1,0,periods,delay;
    return p;
}

int main () {

  int periods=10;
  double delay=25.0;
  string world_path="../../worlds/darwin_cpgs_noise.wbt";

  start_webots(world_path.data());

  unix_socket server;

  server.initSocket(DEFAULT_SOCKET_PATH,0);
  server.wait();

  server.receiveVectorXd();      
  server.sendVectorXd(asmParams(true,periods,delay));
  server.sendVectorXd(VectorXd::Ones(dim)*10);

  asmemory aSm;
  aSm.setMode(0);
  bool end=false;

  aSm.resetTimer();
  while (aSm.isAcquiring()){
    aSm.resetTimer();
    while(aSm.isRunningRollout()){
      server.receiveMsg();

      if (server.c_recvd=='T' && aSm.lastTimeStep()) {
        aSm.resize(NO_CHANGE,aSm.nTimeSteps()+1,NO_CHANGE);
      }
      else if (server.c_recvd=='E' && !aSm.lastTimeStep()) {
        aSm.resize(NO_CHANGE,aSm.index_t()+1,NO_CHANGE);
        end=true;
      }
      else if (server.c_recvd=='E' && aSm.lastTimeStep()) {
        end=true;
      }

      aSm.setCurrentTime(server.v_recvd);
      server.receiveVectorXd();
      if (server.vector_recvd.rows()!=aSm.nSensors()) aSm.resize(server.vector_recvd.rows(),NO_CHANGE,NO_CHANGE);
      aSm.sendToBuffer(server.vector_recvd);

      if (end) break; 
      aSm.incrementTime();
      end=false;
    }
    aSm.incrementSample();
    server.sendMsg('R',-1.0);

    // crashing the program:
    server.closeSocket();

    end=false;
  }

  aSm.learnData();
  server.closeSocket();  
  return 0;
}
```

What could be causing the memory corruption? I assume somethings wrong in the `unix_socket` class, but the data is sent/received correctly, however every time I call `closeSocket()`, even in the middle of the loop sends a memory corruption error.

EDIT: I've tried using Valgrind, and while there seem to be a lot of memory leaks in the program, I don't really know how to interpret the output (first time using Valgrind):

```
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402DB9: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe91 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3874==     in use at exit: 2,451,739 bytes in 107 blocks
==3874==   total heap usage: 316 allocs, 209 frees, 2,454,518 bytes allocated
==3874== 
==3874== Searching for pointers to 107 not-freed blocks
==3874== Checked 2,640,168 bytes
==3874== 
==3874== 59 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 4
==3874==    at 0x4C2C221: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==3874==    by 0x4EF03B8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==3874==    by 0x4EF1D94: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==3874==    by 0x4EF1E72: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==3874==    by 0x4026FE: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874== 
==3874== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3874==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3874==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3874==      possibly lost: 59 bytes in 1 blocks
==3874==    still reachable: 2,451,680 bytes in 106 blocks
==3874==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3874== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3874== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==3874== 
==3874== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3874== ERROR SUMMARY: 1620 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==3874== 
==3874== 1 errors in context 1 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402DB9: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe91 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 1 errors in context 2 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x407100: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402965: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe41 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 1 errors in context 3 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40706E: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402965: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe41 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 1 errors in context 4 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x407100: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4028D8: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe41 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 1 errors in context 5 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40706E: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4028D8: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe41 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 4 errors in context 6 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4070CC: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4028D8: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe41 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 19 errors in context 7 of 10:
==3874== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3874==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==3874==    by 0x406E12: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4070CC: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402965: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x7fefffe41 is on thread 1's stack
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 120 errors in context 8 of 10:
==3874== Invalid write of size 8
==3874==    at 0x408B56: asmemory::sendToBuffer(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402D48: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x5a1e360 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24,000 alloc'd
==3874==    at 0x4C2C73C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==3874==    by 0x40313F: Eigen::internal::aligned_malloc(unsigned long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4054DA: void* Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_malloc<true>(unsigned long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40503C: double* Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_new_auto<double, true>(unsigned long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x404937: Eigen::DenseStorage<double, -1, -1, -1, 0>::resize(long, long, long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40C552: Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::resize(long, long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40CA07: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::resizeLike<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40C3F0: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::_resize_to_match<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40BDD0: Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::lazyAssign<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40B54B: Eigen::internal::assign_selector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, false, false>::run(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40AD46: Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::_set_noalias<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40A0C4: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::_set_selector<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >(Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&, Eigen::internal::false_type const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874== 
==3874== 
==3874== 1471 errors in context 9 of 10:
==3874== Invalid write of size 8
==3874==    at 0x408FD7: asmemory::setCurrentTime(double) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x402B53: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==  Address 0x5c641f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 800 alloc'd
==3874==    at 0x4C2C73C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==3874==    by 0x40313F: Eigen::internal::aligned_malloc(unsigned long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4054DA: void* Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_malloc<true>(unsigned long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40503C: double* Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_new_auto<double, true>(unsigned long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x405F05: Eigen::DenseStorage<double, -1, -1, 1, 0>::resize(long, long, long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x405CFC: Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::resize(long, long) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x407605: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::resizeLike<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x4074E0: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::_resize_to_match<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x40749C: Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::lazyAssign<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > >(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x407477: Eigen::internal::assign_selector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >, false, false>::run(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>&, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x407442: Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::_set_noalias<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > >(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874==    by 0x407408: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::_set_selector<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > >(Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > const&, Eigen::internal::false_type const&) (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)
==3874== 
==3874== ERROR SUMMARY: 1620 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Use a tool like valgrind to help track down memory management problems.

Answer (score 0):

For memory errors

**valgrind --track-origins=yes -v [your program]**

Give the traces of uninitialised memory accesses, that may be resulting in your program's undefined behavior.

For leaks,

**valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes -v [your program]**

The output is in the form of a sets of traces, each trace is analyzed from bottom to top,

for ex.

---

==3874== 59 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 4

==3874==    at 0x4C2C221: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)

==3874==    by 0x4EF03B8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)

==3874==    by 0x4EF1D94: char* std::string::_S_construct(char const*, char const*, std::allocator const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)

==3874==    by 0x4EF1E72: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)

==3874==    by 0x4026FE: main (in /home/joao/CloudPT/Bolsa/Webots/controllers/darwin-pi2/server)

---

The call trace starts from **main** and then calls **basic_string** and then to the function call above it, and so on and finally reaching **new** call, but the function which calls the **new** is **__S_create** function, means that there is no free performed after calling this function or there is no deinit method called for this function call when the program terminated.

HTH